# Getting weird crash on changing device orientation twice

Tags: ios, crash, uiimage, orientation

I am navigationcontroller view ,with toolbar,search bar & tableview.
On device orienatation change twice i see weird

```
*** -[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7a31c00
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x93e06332 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGKILL
    frame #0: 0x93e06332 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x93e05932 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kill$UNIX2003 + 32
    frame #2: 0x01e10e03 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 227
    frame #3: 0x01e10cb2 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    frame #4: 0x00ae1a06 UIKit`-[UIImageView _setViewGeometry:forMetric:] + 295
    frame #5: 0x00ae1c2d UIKit`-[UIImageView setFrame:] + 63
    frame #6: 0x00a2b9f2 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 838
    frame #7: 0x00a2c08a UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 72
    frame #8: 0x00a2b3b5 UIKit`__46-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:]_block_invoke_0 + 73
    frame #9: 0x01e41f1a CoreFoundation`__NSArrayChunkIterate + 362
    frame #10: 0x01e0d635 CoreFoundation`__NSArrayEnumerate + 997
    frame #11: 0x01e0d026 CoreFoundation`-[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 102
    frame #12: 0x00a2b353 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 149
    frame #13: 0x00a2a058 UIKit`-[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 358
    frame #14: 0x00abaf20 UIKit`-[UIViewControllerWrapperView setFrame:] + 193
    frame #15: 0x00acfc13 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 335
    frame #16: 0x00acf81c UIKit`-[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewController] + 155
    frame #17: 0x00ad0899 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 346
    frame #18: 0x00ad09e1 UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 33
    frame #19: 0x00bee5c2 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 222
    frame #20: 0x00a34d21 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 145
    frame #21: 0x01eabe42 CoreFoundation`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 66
    frame #22: 0x0304e679 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 266
    frame #23: 0x03058579 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 231
    frame #24: 0x0304e740 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 184
    frame #25: 0x00a2e938 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutIfNeeded] + 42
    frame #26: 0x00ac898a UIKit`-[UIViewController window:willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 565
    frame #27: 0x00a21ef9 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 4712
    frame #28: 0x00a20c8c UIKit`-[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    frame #29: 0x00a20b97 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 93
    frame #30: 0x00a2017b UIKit`-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 228
    frame #31: 0x00a202ac UIKit`-[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:] + 162
    frame #32: 0x00a20203 UIKit`-[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientationIfRotationEnabled:] + 82
    frame #33: 0x00a20028 UIKit`-[UIWindow _handleDeviceOrientationChange:] + 121
    frame #34: 0x013b8a29 Foundation`__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 40
    frame #35: 0x01e75855 CoreFoundation`___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 85
    frame #36: 0x01e75778 CoreFoundation`_CFXNotificationPost + 1976
    frame #37: 0x012fd19a Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
    frame #38: 0x00bccdb1 UIKit`-[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 220
    frame #39: 0x00a042fd UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1405
    frame #40: 0x00a04c38 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
    frame #41: 0x009f8634 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
    frame #42: 0x01cadef5 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 1274
    frame #43: 0x01e7e195 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #44: 0x01de2ff2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #45: 0x01de18da CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2218
    frame #46: 0x01de0d84 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    frame #47: 0x01de0c9b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #48: 0x01cac7d8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 190
    frame #49: 0x01cac88a GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 103
    frame #50: 0x009f6626 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1163
```

I dont have any code inside delegate

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation supports all orientation
I could find cause of crash

Comment: You should post some code to figure out where the error is. The console says that an UIImage object is deallocated. Perhaps the problem is how to allocate the UIImage object that is deallocated

Comment: I overide UItoolbar class to create custom toolbar with image in background.which cause crash on orientation change

Answer (score 0):

I overide UItoolbar class to create custom toolbar with image in background.which cause crash on orientation change

```
@interface CustomWhiteToolbar : UIToolbar {
}

@end

@implementation CustomWhiteToolbar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"White_bordered_background.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [img release];
    self.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}

@end
```

this cause crash on orientation changes.I have custom toolbar class set to toolbar inside my xib.I couldnt find why did that crash